# Caliburn.Micro building a view/viewmodel in code using MEF

Tags: mef, caliburn.micro

I have an application that uses MEF and Caliburn.Micro. The main view has canvas and a button. The button when clicked, should create a new widget and display it in the canvas. The widget in this case is a UserControl that has a view and viewmodel.
The user can add 0-N of these widgets to the canvas.

I have the widget in the MEF catalog but I can't seem to find an example of how to wire it up in Caliburn.Micro.

Any ideas what I'd write in the main view model when that button is pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a collection of view models that your `Canvas` binds to. In fact, if you use a `Conductor` collection type in Caliburn.Micro (have a look at `Conductor<T>.Collection.AllActive`), then it already has an `Items` collection.

When the button is clicked, your main view model verb (method) can add a new view model to the `Items` collection. Your main view model will therefore need a view model factory injected in order to create these child view models.

Comment: Thanks I need to a bit more testing this is leading me in the right direction!